# Magento Connect is not working after migration

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a problem with Magento after move it from local to live server: Magento connect is not working properly. I will explain it:

I have access to Magento connect, but the extensions are not working.

I have tried to delete the pear.ini file but didn't work. I have tried to delete the app/etc/local.xml file, copying the following files from a clean installation: clear, pear, peardev and pecl, and then running the installation process again, but nothing happened.

Is there a way to get my downloaded extensions working wihtout do a clean install?

Greets to all and I aplogize for my English.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error message? Do they appear at all?

Answer (score 0):

Moving a Magento installation can be difficult. [Here](http://blog.joefallon.net/2011/03/how-to-move-a-magento-installation/) is the procedure that I have used many times with great success.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your /download folder and the /pear folder are owner and group writeable and that the apache or other http user have write access via the group permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions match the webserver's user and delete `downloader/pearlib/pear.ini`.  When you hit the page, it will regenerate the file with the correct paths.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the extensions working I needed to copy all files manually. I don't know why, but I have tried everything and it was the only solution that worked for me.